# Extract best pipeline from GridSearchCV for cross_val_predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

How can I extract the best pipeline from a fit `GridSearchCV`, so that I can pass it on to `cross_val_predict`?

Directly passing the fit `GridSearchCV` object causes `cross_val_predict` to run the whole grid search again, I just want to let the best pipeline be subject to the `cross_val_predict` evaluation.

My self-contained code is below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import metrics

# fetch data data
newsgroups = fetch_20newsgroups(remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories=['comp.graphics', 'rec.sport.baseball', 'sci.med'])
X = newsgroups.data
y = newsgroups.target

# setup and run GridSearchCV
wordvect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', lowercase=True)
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='balanced'))
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', wordvect), ('classifier', classifier)])
scoring = 'f1_weighted'
parameters = {
            'vect__min_df': [1, 2],
            'vect__max_df': [0.8, 0.9],
            'classifier__estimator__C': [0.1, 1, 10]
            }
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=8, scoring=scoring, verbose=1)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(X, y)

### outputs: Fitting 3 folds for each of 12 candidates, totalling 36 fits

# manually extract the best models from the grid search to re-build the pipeline
best_clf = gs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps['classifier']
best_vectorizer = gs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect']
best_pipeline = Pipeline([('best_vectorizer', best_vectorizer), ('classifier', best_clf)])

# passing gs_clf here would run the grind search again inside cross_val_predict
y_predicted = cross_val_predict(pipeline, X, y)
print(metrics.classification_report(y, y_predicted, digits=3))
```

What I am currently doing is manually re-building the pipeline from the `best_estimator_`. But my pipelines usually have more steps such as SVD or PCA, and sometimes I am adding or removing steps and re-running the grid-searches to explore the data. This step has to be then always repeated below when manually re-building the pipeline, which is error-prone.

Is there a way to directly extract the best pipeline from a fit `GridSearchCV`, so that I can pass it to `cross_val_predict` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
y_predicted = cross_val_predict(gs_clf.best_estimator_, X, y)
```

works and returns:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 12 candidates, totalling 36 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  36 out of  36 | elapsed:   43.6s finished
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0      0.920     0.911     0.916       584
          1      0.894     0.943     0.918       597
          2      0.929     0.887     0.908       594

avg / total      0.914     0.914     0.914      1775
```

[Edit] When I tried the code again passing simply `pipeline` (the original pipeline), it returned the same output (as did passing `best_pipeline`). So it's possible you could just work with the Pipeline itself, but I'm not 100% on that.

Answer (score 0):

Name your gridsearch object as you want, then use fit method to get results. You don't need to cross-validate again, because GridSearchCV is basically cross-validation with different parameters(FYI, you can name your own cv object in GridSearchCV, check GridSearchCV in sklearn documentation).

```
any_name = sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)
any_name.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Below is a link of a good guide I found:
https://www.civisanalytics.com/blog/workflows-in-python-using-pipeline-and-gridsearchcv-for-more-compact-and-comprehensive-code/

First answer on SO, hope it helps.

Comment: This  approach doesn't return the individual probabilities which is what the OP asked for.